# REST API update and email address in one record where the ID has multiple records

Tags: rest

What's the equivalent REST method and request for this sql query?

```
UPDATE user 
SET email = 'newemail@etc.com' 
WHERE email = 'oldemail@etc.com' 
AND account_number = 1234
```

Would it be

```
PATCH api/users/1234/oldemail@etc.com
{
    email:"newemail@etc.com"
}
```

or should I create a new method, something like this?

```
PATCH api/update-email/1234
{
     oldEmail:"oldemail@etc.com",
     newEmail:"newemail@etc.com"
}
```

Note: the account_number is not the primary key id

Comment: All of these can technically be correct, and this isn't really that tied to REST.

Answer (score 0):

You are updating an existing record, you should use PATCH instead of POST.

Refs:

[RESTful API Design — PUT vs PATCH](https://medium.com/backticks-tildes/restful-api-design-put-vs-patch-4a061aa3ed0b)

[REST – PUT vs POST](https://restfulapi.net/rest-put-vs-post/)

[RESTful API Design: 13 Best Practices to Make Your Users Happy](https://florimond.dev/blog/articles/2018/08/restful-api-design-13-best-practices-to-make-your-users-happy/)

Comment: I read that and edited the question, thanks. Do you know the answer to which one is best, if any?

Answer (score 0):

> What's the equivalent REST method and request for this sql query?

How would you do it on a web page?  You'd POST form data.

For instance, if you were to

```
GET /emailAddresses
```

and then you happened to notice that there was a mistake in the list that you wanted to fix, you would probably click on the "fix this email" link, which would load a new form

```
GET /fixThisEmail?oldEmail=oldemail@example.com
```

And then you would fill in the replacement address into the form (which would have the original address preloaded into an input control).  Since the /emailAddresses resource is the cachable data that you want to change, the form submission would probably look like

```
POST /emailAddresses
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

oldEmail=oldemail@example.com&newEmail=newemail@example.com
```

If instead you wanted to use a remote authoring idiom, you might reasonably edit your own local copy of the email addresses list to correct the error, and then send the revised representation back to the server

```
GET /emailAddresses

(make the edit in your local copy)

PUT /emailAddresses
```

PATCH is convenient when the list is much bigger than the http headers and the edit is small relative to the size of the list.

```
GET /emailAddresses

(make the edit in your local copy)

PATCH /emailAddresses
```

... but, notice that for both PUT and PATCH, you are going to need to figure out how to extract from the request-body the things that have changed, and compute the right SQL update query to use.  Getting the "old" email address to match on may be painful if it isn't present in the new representation.

You can make that somewhat simpler by using a bespoke patch document representation, but that restricts the range of general purpose clients that can use your API.